# Can not display anything but white screen

Tags: pi-3

Hi i'm new to raspberry pi.
and I want to see screen with tft 2.4inch lcd .
I tried to connect raspberry pi to the lcd throught the connector but it only show white screen without raspberry pi . so i bought the jump cable to connect but i do not know how to connect together.
i really want to know how to solve this problem.

[image]

the raspberry pi is "raspberry pi 3 a+ model" ,
and the display is https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Hot-sale-2-4-inches-LCD_60757060575.html

and the connector is 40-pin FPC to Straight 2x20 IDC Female Socket

i'm not sure if those products match together.
thank you !

Comment: those two devices cannot be directly plugged together

Comment: you need a datasheet for the display to proceed with building an adapter circuit ... do not buy parts that do not have a datasheet available